# My finch task following a light source (java)

Tags: java, finch

I am supposed to make my finch follow a light source, with the following requirements:

-make the finch move towards the light source
- set led colour to blue when light source is detected

- if no light source, finch doesn't move.
- sets led colour to red.

But I'm getting a syntax error on the last bit.

```
myf.quit(); (unreachable code is the error)
```

And my code also doesn't do the required tasks it seems. Where would the issues be?

My code:

```
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;
public class Myfinchtask {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Finch myf = new Finch();
    int[] lightsensors =  myf.getLightSensors();
    int meetsthreshold = 300;
    int lightsensorsaverage = 0;

    while(true){

        lightsensors =  myf.getLightSensors();
        lightsensorsaverage = (lightsensors[0]+lightsensors[1])/2;

        if (lightsensorsaverage < meetsthreshold)
        {
            myf.stopWheels();
            myf.setLED(100, 0, 0);

            while (lightsensorsaverage < meetsthreshold){

                lightsensors =  myf.getLightSensors();
                lightsensorsaverage = (lightsensors[0]+lightsensors[1])/2;

                if (lightsensorsaverage > meetsthreshold){

                    myf.setLED(0, 0, 100);
                    myf.setWheelVelocities(100, 100);


                }
            }


            }
        }

    myf.quit();
    System.exit(0);

    }


}
```

Comment: You never end the outer `while (true)` loop, so `myf.quit();` is never reached.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I see, So how would I end it? Or is that not the right way to use the     while loop

Comment: To end a while loop, you either use `break;`, or use a condition in the `while` that ends the loop when it is done. I have no clue what you are trying to achieve with that code, nor why you have put it in a `while (true)` loop, as such I can't tell you when/where you should end it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so I tweeked the braces around and managed to get the error solved. But my code seems to not run. It says 'connecting to finch this may take a few seconds....' but I assume there's something wrong with my code and not the finch since I ran a sample (example) code which seems to work.

Comment: I am attempting to check the light levels using the light sensors on the finch and I though I'd use a while loop to keep checking if the right light levels are met for the finch to do the tasks.